# apply style with execCommand on arbitrary text

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

i know how to execute `execCommand` on some selected text, but is there a way to execute on some other text in my `contenteditable` div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE, yes. In other browsers, no.

All major desktop browsers implement some form of `document.execCommand()`, which acts only on the user selection. In IE, the `TextRange` object also has an `execCommand` method. For example, the following will turn the text contents of an element green when the user hovers the cursor over it:

```
<div id="test">Here is a test div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById("test");
    div.onmouseover = function() {
        if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            textRange.moveToElementText(div);
            textRange.execCommand("foreColor", false, "green");
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not aware, the `.execCommand` is an IE only non-standard javascript function that should be avoided.

If you tell us what you want to use it for, then we could suggest a standards-compliant alternative.

Comment: `document.execCommand`, which works only on the current selection, is actually well-supported. Firefox has had it since pre-1.0 days, and WebKit since around Safari 2.0, I think. Opera has also supported it since at least 9.0.

Comment: @TimDown `execCommand` seems to indeed be well supported. Is it documented in any specs though? I feel all it's uses are "Hackish"

Comment: It's certainly not consistently implemented. There is an effort at specifying it in HTML5, though how final it is I don't know. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#execCommand

Comment: .execCommand is part of the editing API in HTML5, thus it is not non-standard.  Of course, the HTML5 spec if not finalized, so if they yank it for some reason, I'll have to apologize.  :-)  Read more here:  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#editing-apis

Comment: @james.gariss yes it's in the process of being standardized. But it started as a non-standard extension.